# C# Websocket server not receiving messages from HTML5 client

Tags: c#, html, websocket

I'm attempting to create a bare bones websocket chat room server. My client is able to connect to the server, but it is unable to send messages to the server, despite the server being in a listening state.

When the client connects, a bunch of what looks like header information gets written to the console. But when WebSocket.send() gets executed in Javascript, nothing occurs server side.

HTML:

```
<button id="closeSocket">disconnect</button><br />
<input id = "inputField" /><button id="sendMessage">send</button>
<div id = "output"></div>

<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'websockets.js'></script>
```

Javascript:

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80");

document.getElementById("closeSocket").onclick = closeSocket;
document.getElementById("sendMessage").onclick = sendMessage;

websocket.onopen = function(){
  output("connected");
}

function sendMessage(){
    output("sent: " + document.getElementById('inputField').value);
  websocket.send(document.getElementById('inputField').value);
}

websocket.onmessage = function(e){
  output("got response: " + e.data);
}

function closeSocket(){
    websocket.close();
}

websocket.onclose = function(){
    output("disconnected");
}

function output(t){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += t + "<br />";
}
```

C# server:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WebSocketsTutorial {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("server started");

            while (true) {
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[100];
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer) {
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what is output on the console when the client connects:

[image]

What I'm mainly looking to do is to allow an arbitrary number of connections and ultimately have the server echo a user's submission to all connected clients.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a WebSocket is not just a regular socket. It defines a connection handshake using HTTP and its own framing protocol that you need to use.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

https://hpbn.co/websocket/

Second, you are reading just the first 100 bytes of the request. You should read until the `Read` operation returns 0.

There is a myriad of components you can use to create a WebSocket server, including the default one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets

Comment: How would I read more input than 100 characters? I have it in an infinite loop so I thought it would continually read in 100 byte inputs forever. I'm not sure that explains why the client isn't able to send messages to the server

Comment: Oh that doesn't change anything. I moved the client = server.AcceptTcpClient(); above the while loop and all that did was make it so the loop ran infinitely and scrolled everything off the console window.

Comment: I suspect WebSockets are currently broken, since I haven't been able to get any help from anyone that could get this working and though I've tried this with a PHP server as well and downloaded several demos, it's always been the same. Users can connect but messages can't be sent. A simple working server example that I could send messages to from my very simple html 5 client would be great but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I've had no issue getting the client working. And have used echo servers no problem. But still no way of getting a server of my own to do the same

Comment: As I said, to develop your own websocket server, is not just to open a socket and wait for requests. You can find a WebSocket server done in C# if you are curious about how to do it https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Comment: Thanks I will spend some time with this. It's a very large project though and could take some time